# Magento 2 | get custom attribute of product

Tags: magento2, product

I installed custom product attributes via this:

```
<?php

namespace UO\CheckCartSpecialProducts\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'onbaseurl',
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Online-Nutzung Basis-URL',
                'input' => 'text',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'default' => '',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => ''
            ]
        );

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'onsupportmail',
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Online-Nutzung Support-Email',
                'input' => 'text',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'default' => '',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => ''
            ]
        );

    }
}
?>
```

Now I need to want to get them in my code.

> $product->getCustomAttribute('onbaseurl')->value()

doesn't work.

It says

> getCustomAttribute('onbaseurl')

is null

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below codes:

```
$product->getOnbaseurl();

$product->getOnsupportmail();
```

OR

```
$product->getData('onbaseurl');

$product->getData('onsupportmail');
```

It should work.

Answer (score 2):

Please use below.

```
$product->getData("onbaseurl");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->getProduct()->getAttributeText('attribute_text');
```

use above code for get custom attribute value. ans also first fetch product collection if not.

Answer (score 1):

Use this below code :

```
$product->getResource()->getAttribute('onbaseurl')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);

$product->getResource()->getAttribute('onsupportmail')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Item::getAttribute() :/

Comment: Make sure $product is current product collection. Like => $product = $this->_registry->registry('current_product');

Comment: I think that error happens because $item is of class "Item" and not "Product"

Comment: You can get product id using $item->getProductId(). Then, $this->_product->load($item->getProductId());

Comment: Then, if above answer not working one more option available. $product = $this->_product->load($item->getProductId()); $product->getAttributeText('onbaseurl');

Comment: this is not working sadly :/